# clock_t division results in 0

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to get some basic timing going in my **C** program.
Basically I want to flip a bit a few times a seconds for a defined period.
My problem is division doesn't seem to work properly with variable of the 
`clock_t` type.

Here is a minimal program which shows the problem, I tested it with both
GCC and clang:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CLOCKS_PER_BLINK CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 4L

int main() {
    printf("%li\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("%li\n", CLOCKS_PER_BLINK);
    printf("%li\n", 4L);
    printf("%li\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC/CLOCKS_PER_BLINK);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
1000000
250000
4
0
```

I would have expected for the last line to return `4`.

Comment: Note: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is not necessarily `long`.  It is type `clock_t` which could be `int`, `double`, ...  `printf("%li\n", (long) CLOCKS_PER_SEC);` or `printf("%lli\n", (long long) CLOCKS_PER_SEC);` are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CLOCKS_PER_SEC/CLOCKS_PER_BLINK` macro evaluates/compiles to: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 4L`, which, when run, gives 1/4, which gives 0 due to integer division.

You need parentheses for this to work as intended: `CLOCKS_PER_SEC/(CLOCKS_PER_BLINK)`, or as alk suggests, adjust the macro to use parentheses: `#define CLOCKS_PER_BLINK (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 4L)`

The problem here is that macros evaluate extremely literally, which is why you're not supposed to do things like put semicolons in them. They're basically find and replace or copypasta, so it's good to be extra careful around them.

Comment: Better apply the parentheses to the macro: `#define CLOCKS_PER_BLINK (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 4L)`!

Comment: Wrapped the value for the macro definition in parentheses, it is working now, thank you for saving my sanity.